# How to using annotation @RefreshScope with spingboot : connectionFactory?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

how to refresh `connectionFactory` or `connectionpool`,such as `dataSource`,`JedisConnectionFactory`... when the springboot application is running?
(I used springcould-config to update my configs)

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.redis.pool")
public JedisPoolConfig getRedisConfig() {
    JedisPoolConfig config = new JedisPoolConfig();
    return config;
}

@Bean(name = "redisConnection")
public JedisConnectionFactory getConnectionFactory() {
    JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
    JedisPoolConfig config = getRedisConfig();
    factory.setPoolConfig(config);
    factory.setPassword(password);
    factory.setHostName(hostName);
    factory.setPort(port);
    factory.setDatabase(database);
    return factory;
}

...

pseudocode:

onChangeListener function then

refreshScope.refresh("redisConnection");
```

but it does not work,however, some files with `@Value("${spring.redis.host}")` 
   it change

Comment: your code doesn't use `@RefreshScope`, should it?

Comment: actually，I used  this annotation on the class

Comment: It has a problem when @RefreshScope on the getConnectionFactory function ,springboot can’t start-up. However，the real issue : when spring IOC container finished registering and it used by other services,how can i refresh this connection beans.

Comment: The code refreshScope.refresh("redisConnection") is my mistake，I used this code : refreshScope.refresh("redisConfig"); on my class with \@Configuration  &  \@RefreshScope   actually